# How do I access these inner variables in ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am trying to learn some basic ruby metaprogramming and have been given a class like this:

```
class A
  def initialize
    @a = 11
    @@a = 22 
    a = 33
  end

  @a = 1
  @@a = 2
  a = 3
end
```

I need to output these variables like so without modifying the class:

```
1
2
3
11
22
33
```

Here is my code so far:

```
p A.instance_variable_get(:@a) #=> 1
p A.class_variable_get(:@@a) #=> 2

A.new.instance_eval do
    puts @a #=> 11
end
```

Now how do I access the remaining variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class A
  def initialize
    @a = 11
    @@a = 22 
    a = 33
  end

  @a = 1
  @@a = 2
  a = 3
end

p A.instance_variable_get(:@a) # >> 1
p A.class_variable_get(:@@a) # >> 2

p A.new.instance_variable_get(:@a) >> 11

p A.class_variable_get(:@@a) # >> 22
```

Note that line to get var 22 is the same that gets var 2, because it is the same variable and its value was overwritten when you called `A.new`.

As for plain `a` variables, you can't get them, because they were local vars and don't exist anymore.

Comment: And how do I output 33 and 3? Also why does that code work? After A is instantiated, why does class_variable_get evaluate to 22? While before it evaluated to 2?

Comment: So Sergio, what exactly are @a and @@a variables outside of the initialize method? What do we call them in ruby?

Comment: `@@a` is the same inside and outside of `initialize` method. `@a` is an instance variable either on an instance of `A` or `A` itself (depending on where you assign its value).

Comment: So when you say A itself, that means @a is an instance variable of `class A` as opposed to an instance of `class A`?

Comment: @AmitErandole: yes, instance variable on the `A` object. Classes are regular objects in ruby and can have instance variables.

Comment: Ok I think I got it - I am marking this as the right answer. If there is any place on the internet where I can learn more specifically about this topic, please share some links. I am still a bit confused.

Comment: I read books. This is a good one: [Metaprogramming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby).

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the final solution for those interested:

```
catcher = class A
  def initialize
    @a = 11
    @@a = 22
    a = 33
  end

  @a = 1
  @@a = 2
  a = 3
end
```

Bit of a cheat on that one but this works

```
puts A.class_eval { @a } #=> 1
puts A.class_variable_get :@@a #=> 2

puts A.new.instance_eval { @a } #=> 11

puts catcher #=> 3

puts A.new.send :initialize #=> 33
```